# postfix relayhost send as user@example.com

Tags: postfix, dynamic-dns

I have a working setup of a postfix installation, but because I have a dynamic IP, gmail refuses any messages I send from my server.
I searched arround and found that with relayhost I can send messages, but when I set it up with my gmail account, all messages that are sent were from my gmail account...
Is there a way to look like they are sent from my domain? 
I don't want to buy a DNS.

Any advice is welcome!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to [add your other address to your Gmail account](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en) in order to send mail through it; otherwise Gmail will rewrite the From header. It will send a confirmation email to verify you own that address, so you'll need to make sure delivery is set up correctly.